# flutter : concert class not called in abstract class has a static method

Tags: flutter, abstract-class

I have this abstract class :

```
abstract class PostEditorInterface {
  static List<String>? getFreinds(String selectedUser) {}
}
```

Now I implemented this class:

```
class PostEditorImpl implements PostEditorInterface {
  List<String>? getFreinds(String selectedUser) {
    return CitiesService.getSuggestions(selectedUser);
  }
}
```

But when I call getFreinds the concert class is not called ?

```
 cities = PostEditorInterface.getFreinds(selectedUser);
```

I got null ?

**I have to mentioned that abstract class and It's implementation is in a separate package.**

Comment: You can't override static methods.

Comment: Imagine 2 packages exist and one package must fulfill some data for the first package. What is your Idea ? @Apealed

Comment: When you call `PostEditorInterface.getFreinds` you are executing the empty-bodied method from the `PostEditorInterface` class. `PostEditorImpl` doesn't actually change the implemented class's `static` members.

Comment: Overriding `static` members makes no sense.  If you could override `static` members, what if there are multiple classes that derive from `PostEditorInterface` and you try to call `PostEditorInterface.getFreinds`?  Which derived class's implementation should be used?

Comment: Imagine there are 2 packages. in package A I have an abstract class that has static members. Now In package B I make a concrete class from the abstract class. Now I want to when In package A call static method , the implementation from class B is called @jamesdlin

Comment: And how do you expect the implementation from class B to be called?  Magic? Imagine that there is another concrete class C that also implements the abstract class A.  How is the compiler supposed to know whether to use B's implementation or C's?

Comment: Yes, but there is no way to handle this situation? @jamesdlin

Comment: There is no logical way to handle that situation, so no, there is no way in Dart to handle that situation either.  Instead of using `static` methods, use some (possibly global) object instance with overridable instance methods.

Comment: thanks, I want to be completely separated  these 2 packages without any common dependencies. instead of an interface to communication.  @jamesdlin

Answer (score 1):

Static methods cannot be overridden in Dart. [See this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/356).

Instead do something like:

```dart
abstract class PostEditorInterface {
  List<String>? f();
}

class PostEditorImpl extends PostEditorInterface {
  @override
  List<String>? f() { return ['hi']; }
}

// ...

final PostEditorInterface postEditor = PostEditorImpl();

final list = postEditor.f();
```

An example with two packages:

```dart
// package A
abstract class PostEditorInterface {
  List<String>? f();
}

void methodA(PostEditorInterface postEditor) {
  // no access to Impl, no problem. We have the interface.
  print(postEditor.f()); // prints the list
}
```

```dart
// package B
import 'package A'; // let's say this works!

class PostEditorImpl extends PostEditorInterface {
  @override
  List<String>? f() { return ['hi']; }
}

// now use methodA as usual since here you have access to Impl

methodA(PostEditorImpl()); // it's going to print the list ['hi']
```

Comment: dear Hossein in main package I don't access to PostEditorImpl @Hossein Yousefi

Comment: I just have Interface and I just can call this interface and I expect it's concert called.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the code is just an example. Let's say that you have a function that gets a `PostEditorInterface` as a parameter, you can just use the methods from it as usual and then your second package gives the implementation.

Comment: I'll update my answer with an example use case.

Comment: ‍final PostEditorInterface postEditor = PostEditorImpl(); where I have do that ?

Comment: In the package that has `PostEditorInterface` I don't access to `PostEditorImpl` @HosseinYousefi

Comment: @CyrustheGreat I updated my answer, hopefully it answers your question.

Comment: @CyrustheGreat I don't quite know the specifics of what you're doing but this is the essence of what you're trying to do. I suggest going through this once more and try to understand it. You can see how package A doesn't know what the implementation of package B is going to be. However, it still can print the list in its method. And package B can implement the abstract class to its liking and use the functionalities of package A. I think the rest should become clear if you try out some examples. Cheers!

Comment: I created a flutter package. Inside this package, I made a abstract class. Now in package, I created an Example and I want to implement this interface into example .

Comment: You know ` List<String>? f();` f method has a parameter as input  List<String>? f(String input);` And input comes from package A and concert class Package B get this input and call API and return a list